# Add Factbox to role center page

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, enterprise-portal

According to [Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh209358.aspx) it should be possible to add a Factbox component to role center pages. But I don't have the option to add this when clicking "Add new web part".

I can find plenty of resources on how to [customize or modify](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh179454(v=nav.71).aspx) existing factboxes. But I can't find any guidance on how to add a new one to an existing page.

[image: Options]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I remember, you can add FactBox only with ListPage form to EP page. 
Please, take a look at this white-paper https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg886593.aspx

Comment: I figured as much :). Thanks for the answer.